# Write small MSACCESS app to export all tables from any selected *.accdb file to .CSV files

Tags: export-to-csv

I'm trying to write a small, canned application in MSACCESS (hopefully boiled into an executable) to allow a user to pick any "*.accdb" file and simply export all the tables in the selected db to .CSV files.

Please note: this code works fine with used WITHIN a certain db, but I'm seeking a tool to open ANOTHER db and export from there.

With the following code, I get an error: 3011 - The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'FK Data Extract'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'FK Data Extract' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

Thanks for any ideas.

Steve

```
    Option Compare Database
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Toggle12_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Dim f As Office.FileDialog
    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    
    ' Show the dialog. If the method returns True, the user picked at least one file.
    ' If the method returns False, the user clicked Cancel.
    If f.Show Then
        'MsgBox f.SelectedItems.Count & " file(s) were chosen."
        MsgBox f.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    Call OpenDb(f.SelectedItems(1))
    End Sub

    Public Function OpenDb(sDb As String)
    On Error GoTo Err_ExportDatabaseObjects
    Dim oAccess         As Access.Application
    Dim BigIn_fn        As Variant
    
    Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")    'Create a new Access instance
    With oAccess
        .OpenCurrentDatabase sDb    'Open the specified db
        .Visible = True             'Ensure it is visible to the end-user
        .UserControl = True
            

        Dim td As TableDef
        Dim d As Document
        Dim c As Container
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim sExportLocation As String
        
             
        sExportLocation = "C:\users\steve\"
        
        For Each td In .CurrentDb.TableDefs 'Tables
            Debug.Print td.Name
            If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
                DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , td.Name, sExportLocation & "Table_" & td.Name & ".csv", True
            End If
            Next td
        Set db = Nothing
        Set c = Nothing
        
        MsgBox "All database objects have been exported as a csv file to " & sExportLocation, vbInformation
        
Exit_ExportDatabaseObjects:
        Exit Function
        
Err_ExportDatabaseObjects:
        Debug.Print Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
        MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
        Resume Exit_ExportDatabaseObjects
     
    End With
    Exit Function
    End Function



Error as above: 3011 - The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'FK Data Extract'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'FK Data Extract' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.
```

Comment: Try  frame all object names with square brackets. "FK Data extract" ->"[FK Data extract]". For table name td.Name ->"[" & td.name & "]".

Comment: OK, I tried this. Unfortunately, I still get the same error with the brackets. "...could not find the object '[FK Data Extract]'.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `End With` and `Exit Function` before the `Exit_` label.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to offer an explanation of why this change is necessary and why it solves the problem?